# Одновременное использование двух интернет провайдеров Mikrotik

Tags: сеть, mikrotik, nat, vlan

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста. Нужно организовать сеть для работы ЧОП. Есть сервис который обрабатывает запросы устройств. Проблема в том, что устройства отправляют запросы на 2-х провайдеров которые подключены в одну сеть, но второй провайдер начинает работать только после автопереключения на него. Возможно реализовать одновременное и непрерывное получение запросов по двум WAN портам, а к примеру HTTP и HTTPS промаркировать чтобы использовался только 1 провайдер?

---

Вот ссылка для решения данного вопроса https://habr.com/ru/post/313342/?_ga=2.125035914.1047870027.1628165513-131236779.1628165513

Comment: В общем случае задача явно нерешаемая. Просто представь, что есть два устройства, одно в сети первого прова, второе в сети другого - и у обоих один и тот же серый адрес...

Comment: Ну в этом ничего такого не вижу, серый адрес выдаётся коммутатором каждого провайдера, так что он тут роли на мой взгляд не меняет

Comment: Возможно балансировка решает этот вопрос, но я не уверен